# ArcGIS 10.5.1 "Name of an entry in the codedvaluedomain is empty" error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

[image]I am trying to create a model in model builder that will convert a CSV file to a dbf and then import that as a domain into a specified geodatabase.

I was able to do this in another model by exporting the domains of one geodatabase (using Domain to Table) into another (using Table to Domain).

This time, however, the model crashes stating:
"Error 999999: Error Executing function. The name of an entry in the CodedValueDomain is empty. (domain name: Py Test)
Failed to execute (Table to Domain)."
I am typing in the names of the fields for code and description ("code" and "description", respectively.)
In my other model, I have to type the fields in by hand, but it still works. This time I don't seem to have as much luck.

I thought it was because of the specific model parameters that are defined up to that point, but it still follows the logical order.

I am not able to post a screenshot.

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 2):

I found that the description field cannot be empty. The description field is a required field and cannot be made optional.

I went back into my CSV and wrote "null" for each line of the description field. Using the description field as a way to number the code field also helps. It works now.